# Keras model.predict( ) incompatible dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to predict with a model using Keras and TensorFlow. While using the model.predict() function, let's say I am giving it a np.array of shape `[1,2160,8]`, an error is thrown by the program, stating :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 2160, 8]
```

Additionally, the np.array I am feeding is of shape `[1,2160,8]`, but the error says it is of shape [None, 2160, 8].

This is my code for predicting :

```
test = np.array([[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]*2160], np.uint32)

reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model_cnn')
reconstructed_model.summary()
res = reconstructed_model.predict(test)
```

model.summary is as follows:

```
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_9 (Conv1D)            (None, 2160, 8)           40        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_9 (Flatten)          (None, 17280)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 17280)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 1)                 17281     
=================================================================
Total params: 17,321
Trainable params: 17,321
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The error tells us that something is wrong with the input shape of your array that you are feeding. In this case, the error specifies that the last dimension of your array in incorrect. The last dimension should be of size 1, not 8. Try changing your array to be of size (1, 2160, 1).

Comment: Hey Richard, thanks for the speedy reply and help. This seems to be working!